# Write $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\rho+\theta)\\\sin(\rho+\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ as a linear combination of vectors in orthonormal basis $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

I've verified that $A=\left\lbrace\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(\theta)\\ \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\right\rbrace$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^2$ with respect to the scalar product $\langle, \rangle$.

Let $\rho \in \mathbb R$.

I must be able to write $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\rho+\theta)\\\sin(\rho+\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $A$.

Using the scalar product I get:

$c_1 =\cos(\theta)\cos(\rho+\theta)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\rho+\theta) = \cos(p + 2\theta)$ $c_2 =\sin(\rho+\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\cos(\rho+\theta) = \sin(p + \theta-\theta) = \sin(\rho)$

However inserting numbers for $\rho, \theta$ I don't get equality on my calculator.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: $\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B) = \cos(A-B)$, so when $A=\rho+\theta, B= \theta$ then $c_1=\cos(\rho+\theta)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\rho+\theta)\sin(\theta) = \cos(\rho)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, using trigonometric sum of angles identities

$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
\cos(\rho+\theta) \\
\sin(\rho+\theta)  \end{array} \right]=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
\cos(\rho)\cos(\theta)- \sin(\rho)\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\rho)\cos(\theta)+ \cos(\rho)\sin(\theta)  \end{array} \right]=\cos(\rho)\left[ \begin{array}{c}
\cos(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta)  \end{array} \right]+\sin(\rho)\left[ \begin{array}{c}
-\sin(\theta) \\
\cos(\theta)  \end{array} \right]$

Comment: Thank you. Also do you see where I make a mistake ?

Comment: I see that $c_2$ is correct. But having reviewed the sum formulas again, the constant $c_1$ is right also ?

Comment: Your $c_2$ term is indeed correct. The $c_1$ constant is incorrect - the last term should be $\cos(\rho+\theta-\theta)=\cos(\rho)$, because $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ and not a $+$ sign.

Comment: $\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B) = \cos(A-B)$, so when $A=\rho+\theta, B= \theta$ then $c_1=\cos(\rho+\theta)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\rho+\theta)\sin(\theta) = \cos(\rho)$

Comment: Ahh thanks for your help.